# Linux - bash - send email preserve whitelines

Tags: linux, bash, email, unix, newline

below is the function used to send email

```
send_mail(){
    SUBJECT="test"

    cat << EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t ${TO_LIST}
    From: test@gmail.com
    
    To: $TO_LIST
    Subject: $SUBJECT
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <BODY>
     echo "$result"
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
    
    EOF
    }
```

The value of result when printed in the program in

1

2

3

but in the mail it was coming as

1 2 3

how can i preserve the new lines

Comment: Add a tag <br/> at the end of each line

Comment: the inclusion of `cat` here is pointless.  `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t ${TO_LIST} << EOF` would work just as well with one less process

Comment: how can i have file content in the body of the email

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bash issue.

HTML defines newlines to just be space characters. You will need to add a `<br>` tag if you wanted to have a line break in HTML.

However. You win nothing by using HTML in your email, and should just use plaintext instead.

Matter of fact, this looks actually broken, as the HTML content needs to be in a mime part that explicitly declares that it's the HTML part. So even after you fix the line breaks, email clients might choose to throw away all your HTML and reduce the message to its textual content.